# bootstrap 4 video full height and width for the remainder of the viewport

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

as you can see by the picture below the video isn't at 100% height. how do i get the video to fill out the remaining space below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid h-100 red">
  <div class="row justify-content-left h-100">
   <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="yellow">
    <h3 class="display-3">Sublime</h3>
    <h4 class="display-4">What we do.</h4>
    <p class="p-3 my-3">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores voluptates at provident fugiat ipsam voluptas illum quidem dolores pariatur, culpa, ab optio eum perferendis! Et magni doloremque voluptatem temporibus maiores?</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8 blue px-0">
    <!--mask color-->
    <div class="view">
     <!--video Source-->
     <video class="video-fluid" autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="/videos/171003A_009_2K.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
     </video>
     <div class="mask rgba-indigo-light"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[`

```css
.video-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thats the aspect ratio of the video, if you stretch the height you will either crop the sides or it will be skewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<video>` tag has this class

```
.video-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

`width: 100%` tells the browser to make the video take up 100% of the width its allocated, and given that you have it next to that side panel it'll take up from the end of that panel to the end of the browser. The `heigh: auto` will set the height to fit the aspect ratio of the `<video>` so if it's 16:9 and it's given 1600px width it'll make the height 900px.

You can try setting the height also to be 100%, however  because of the aspect ratio being different it'll be different than you expect. You can if you want have the video be rendered larger and then center it in the white space so you don't see all of the video but it fills all of the screen without looking completely off.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said...you probably don't want the height to be 100% as it will stretch the image or content will be lost. You can however...optimize your CSS for the best ratio by adding a one more line:

```
.video-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
}
```